# realm-js very slow inserts

Tags: react-native, realm

I get about 5 inserts per second with this code which is nowhere near the advertised speeds of Realm so I'm wondering what I could be doing wrong.

Since I didn't find a way of bulk inserting records into realm i'm doing a loop to write them one by one:

```
const save = (contacts) => {
    realm.write(() => {
        for (let i = 0, len = contacts.length; i < len; i++) {
            realm.create('Contact', {
                name    : contacts[i].name.toString(),
                recordID: contacts[i].recordID.toString()
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How many contacts are there?

Comment: 50..it takes about 10 seconds to add those.

Comment: What is the hardware? How many fields does `Contact` have? How many elements does `contacts` have?

Comment: Did you find any fix to this?